# Android Job Scheduler starting immediately (API level 21 and above)

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have a job scheduler that schedules the backup job service for daily/weekly/monthly. But Once I call `jobscheduler.schedule(jobInfo)` the job starts immediately.

Keep in mind I'm calling the `jobBuilder.setPriodic(duration)` with only interval millis and not flex time (since that alternative requires API level 24)
I want to know

1. What conditions are making the job start immediately
2. How can I delay the starting of this job with specific amount of delay.

   ```
   ComponentName backupJob = new ComponentName(TelloApplication.applicationContext, BackupJobService.class);
   JobInfo.Builder jobBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(TelloConstants.BACKUP_ID, backupJob);
   jobBuilder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);
   jobBuilder.setPeriodic(duration);
   JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
   if (duration == 0) {
       scheduler.cancel(TelloConstants.BACKUP_ID);
   } else {
       scheduler.schedule(jobBuilder.build());
   }
   ```

Adding logcat

```
2018-12-05 12:26:16.716 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev D/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: Scheduling Job For 604800 Seconds
2018-12-05 12:26:16.765 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev W/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: OnStartJob initiating Sign-inWed Dec 05 12:26:16 GMT+05:00 2018
2018-12-05 12:26:16.765 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev W/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: OnStartJob initiating Sign-inWed Dec 05 12:26:16 GMT+05:00 2018
2018-12-05 12:26:16.768 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev W/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: Sign-in success, starting service
2018-12-05 12:26:16.768 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev W/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: Sign-in success, starting service
2018-12-05 12:26:16.775 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev D/com.udna.tellotalk.services.TelloBackUpService: onCreate: TELLO BACKUP STARTED
2018-12-05 12:26:16.776 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev D/com.udna.tellotalk.services.TelloBackUpService: onStartCommand: 
2018-12-05 12:26:16.784 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev D/com.udna.tellotalk.services.TelloBackUpService: sendServiceReference: 
2018-12-05 12:26:16.786 16871-16871/com.udna.tellotalk.exp.dev D/05-Dec-2018 12:26 PM :: Starting background backup for messages
```

Comment: have you checked logcat during the call?

Comment: I've added the logcat but it only contains my logs, no system event logged on execution.